# expressjs in memory storage

Tags: node.js, express

I am looking for a sample program /Explantion how to use inmemory storage in express.
I want to store the sessionid of valid users so that I need not do the authentication repeatedly.
I understand as it is inmemory the data is gone on a restart.

Please let me know ..

Comment: StackOverflow is not a search engine - please review the Node.js/ExpressJS documentation and API reference. I was able to find a few results with a quick Google. There are even some existing SO questions that might be helpful. That being said, we'd be happy to answer a specific question you had regarding Node/Express/etc.

Comment: @SimpleCoder , Thank you for the reply. I agree this is nt search ...I did search and got confused with some questions. As you suggested I will post the actual questions in all I searched

Comment: What are you using for session storage?  Redis?

Comment: @Brad,I have users logging and browsing my website. so once they are loged in I want to store that sessionID so that in subsequent HTTP request of that sessionid is present I dont want to do authentication. I am trying to use for now sessionStore - In memory. Redis and all I am not planning at this point of time . my undeerstanding is that if I am able to get the basic inmemory I can extent to any storage.I saw sessionStore.get to get the value. I am looking how I can delete a entry when the user logges out and all that type of information ..

Comment: Well, for your problem of storage, I would just use Redis.  You can have it write to disk.  Plus then, you will be able to easily expand your site to multiple servers with a single session store.

Comment: @Brad, Thank you. I see what you are telling now ..also can you please tell me any reference for operations on Redis. I know it is a key-store like Keeping data and Removing data ...

Comment: Check this link for some info:  http://soenkerohde.com/2012/04/using-redis-as-node-js-express-session-storage-on-heroku/  There are some specifics about Heroku, but the concept applies generally.

Comment: Please stop telling people to use redis when they just want to keep a user logged in. You are actually telling them to add a whole new database so that they can get an id out of redis by using an id that was stored in a cookie. You could just use session cookies and store your user id directly inside the cookie. @The learner: http://enome.github.com/application-generator/ click on cookies and Sessions(Cookies).

Comment: @Pickels, Thanks for the reply. in this case I dont see /storing the session.id? how do we achieve that when not using the Redis 9or) any DB